# Eigen Broadcast Comparison

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

In Eigen we can compare two arrays component wise. We can also use [broadcasting](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html) to add a (suitably sized) vector to a matrix. However, these two do not combine in the obvious way to allow row/column-wise comparison operations. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

using vect_t = Matrix<double, 1, 3>;
using matr_t = Matrix<double, 5, 3>;

int main()
{
    vect_t l(0.1,0.1,0.1);
    vect_t u(0.3,0.3,0.3);
    matr_t X;
    X << 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
         0.1, 0.2, 0.1,
         0.2, 0.2, 0.2,
         1.0, 0.0, 0.2,
         0.2, 0.4, 0.4;

    auto Y = l.array() < u.array(); // okay, gives [1, 1, 1]
    auto Z = X.array().rowwise() + l.array();
    // okay, gives
    // 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,
    // 0.2, 0.3, 0.2,
    // 0.3, 0.3, 0.3,
    // 1.1, 0.1, 0.3,
    // 0.3, 0.5, 0.5;

    //auto W = X.array().rowwise() < l.array(); // does not compile
    // would expect (via broadcasting) something like 
    // 1, 1, 1,
    // 0, 0, 0,
    // 0, 0, 0,
    // 0, 1, 0,
    // 0, 0, 0

    cout << X << endl << endl;
    cout << Y << endl << endl;
    cout << Z << endl << endl;
    //cout << W << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How is it possible to achieve this sort of row-wise comparison?

*Comment: It seems to me, that it should be possible for this to work nicely. Is just a case that it has not been implemented yet or am I missing something?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever `rowwise()` or `colwise()` does not work, you can use [`replicate`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a04021dfbd1ae63f30c61e58fb827ff5f). In your case:

```
auto W = X.array() < l.array().replicate(X.rows(), 1);
```

or

```
auto W = X.array() < l.array().colwise().replicate(X.rows());
```

Comment: Thanks again @chtz. Are there any performance considerations doing it this way rather than the (non functional) other way?

Comment: When compiled with optimization the `replicate` syntax should lead to the same code as the `colwise`/`rowwise` variant (if both are possible). If you notify a difference somewhere, I would consider it as a bug.